# Configuring dask gateway via env vars

Tags: dask, dask-gateway

In dask gateway's config docs, there is a setting [adaptive period](https://gateway.dask.org/api-server.html#c.ClusterConfig.adaptive_period).  How does this interact with the standard `dask.config` variable `DASK_DISTRIBUTED__ADAPTIVE__INTERVAL`?  In general, the [GatewaySchedulerService](https://github.com/dask/dask-gateway/blob/7d1659db8b2122d1a861ea820a459fd045fc3f02/dask-gateway/dask_gateway/scheduler_preload.py#L122) seems to have a parameters that mimic some `dask.config` options.

Are the following dask config vars used or ignored when using a gateway?

- DASK_DISTRIBUTED__SCHEDULER__WORKER_TTL
- DASK_DISTRIBUTED__ADAPTIVE__INTERVAL
- DASK_DISTRIBUTED__ADAPTIVE__WAIT_COUNT
- DASK_DISTRIBUTED__ADAPTIVE__TARGET_DURATION

If they are used, where should they be set?  In the configuration yaml at `gateway.backend.scheduler.extraContainerConfig`, or some other place?

Comment: Please raise an issue on the dask-gateway github repo, so we don't loose track of this

Comment: Raised: https://github.com/dask/dask-gateway/issues/400